# Is quotient of fibration a fibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, model-categories

Assume $f:X\to Y$ is a fibration, and given quotient maps $X\to X/R_X,Y\to Y/R_Y$ is compatible with $f$, is there some condition to ensure that $\bar{f}:X/R_X\to Y/R_Y$ being a fibration?

My aim is to consider the following question.
Let $X,Y$ be two simplicial spaces, i.e. functors $\Delta^{op}\to\mathcal{U}$, here $\mathcal{U}$ denote the category of compactly generated spaces.
Assume that a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is degreewise (Serre/Hurewicz) fibration,i.e. $X_n\to Y_n$ is (Serre/Hurewicz) fibration. I wonder whether the geometric realization $|f|:|X|\to |Y|$ is a fibration.
By definition, $|X|=\dfrac{\amalg_n(X_n\times|\Delta^n|)}{(\alpha x,t)\sim(x,\alpha t)}$, $|Y|=\dfrac{\amalg_n(Y_n\times|\Delta^n|)}{(\alpha y,t)\sim(y,\alpha t)}$
where $\alpha:[n]\to[m]$ in $\Delta$ acts naturally as $\alpha:|\Delta^n|\to|\Delta^m|,\alpha:X_m\to X_n,\alpha:Y_m\to Y_n$
Under the assumption that each $X_n\to Y_n$ is fibration, $\amalg_n(X_n\times|\Delta^n|)\to\amalg_n(Y_n\times|\Delta^n|)$ is a fibration.
Intuitively, $|X|\to|Y|$ is a fibration by gluing up the fibrations $X_n\times|\Delta^n|\to Y_n\times|\Delta^n|$.
I remember that in general quotient doesn't plays well on fibrations. But maybe this case is better than usual?

Comment: What is the reason for showing that $\bar f$ is a fibration?  Are you trying to commute pullbacks past geometric realizations, or is there some other application that you have in mind?